# How can I get copyright or product name for a DLL or EXE file with C/C++?

Tags: winapi

I wrote a C++ program to get a DLL or EXE file's Copyright, Product Name and file version. Refer to the blog [Import Table](http://win32assembly.programminghorizon.com/pe-tut6.html), just like right clicking a file and showing its properties.

[image: the properties of file mfc140.dll]

I got the file version, but I can't get the copyright string. When I debugged into the code, I found the Info inside which member index is 7 is empty.

[image: Info inside]

And I got NULL RVA for copyright string.

[image: debug]

Can you help me explain this issue? Or can you provide me a solution that I can get its copyright?

```
PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR import_desc =
        (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)get_ptr_from_rva(
            image->FileHeader->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[1].VirtualAddress,
            image->FileHeader, image->MappedAddress);
PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR import_copyright =
        (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)get_ptr_from_rva(
            image->FileHeader->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[7].VirtualAddress,
            image->FileHeader, image->MappedAddress);
```

Comment: Use the [proper api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winver/nf-winver-getfileversioninfow).

Comment: This information is stored in the version resource, which can be accessed by APIs.

Comment: @HansPassant, as that API page's remarks says, **File version info has fixed and non-fixed part. The fixed part contains information like version number. The non-fixed part contains things like strings.**. I always can get the file version already with **VS_FIXEDFILEINFO** structure, but I want to get the copyright string. What is the name of non-fixed part structure?

Comment: Nothing? This must be the wrong link. I'll take the 5 upvotes on the first link.